# Form validation in Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I want to show errors for all the form, not single field. So I did this:

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        AddUserForm addUserForm = (AddUserForm) target;

        if (addUserForm.getPassword().length() == 0) {    
            errors.reject("Message error");
        } 

    }
```

Now I'm using `reject` method instead of `rejectValue`, because I don't need to set error message to one field.

And this is my jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="addUserForm"
    class="form-horizontal" style="width: 510px;">

            <form:errors ??? />

...
```

Which attribute should I use now? I was trying this:

```
<form:errors commandName="addUserForm"/>
```

But doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are rejecting by using a fieldName in form object as:

```
    errors.rejectValue("fieldName", "errorMessage");
```

This you can display in view as:

```
    <form:errors path="fieldName"/>
```

If you are rejecting without specifying the fieldname in form object i.e., raising the error on whole form object then you can set these errors as:

```
    errors.reject("Message error");
```

This you can display in view without any attributes as:

```
    <form:errors/>
```